# php csv dynamic columns

Tags: php, csv

I'm design a shopping cart that will allow users to upload products in csv format. The problem is that one of the columns contains dynamic sub columns. The best way to explain this is an example of a product data:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 412
    [description] => this is the description for phat cars

    [title] => Phat Cars
    [price] => 2500.00
    [custom] => Array
        (
            [custom_info] => Array
                (
                )

            [custom_price] => Array
                (
                )
        )

)
```

The field custom[custom_info] and custom[custom_price] could contain any number of fields. I can't think of a solution to have dynamic columns using csv but thought I'd throw the problem out there and see if anybody has any suggestion.

Comment: It's not a great solution, but you could use multiple lines. I've mostly only done this for exporting data to a CSV file though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invent a different notation for this special column - defferent delimiter or json. But this will be hard to write in excel.

I had the same problem once where we had to import courier deliveries with any number of sub-packages. So we allowed to create only one sub-package via CSV and as many as you like via web site.

A better way would be to import this data via WEB services.

Comment: thanks for your reply. When you say WEB services, do you mean writing our own frontend forms to allow users manually add the data? We already have a 'dashboard' in place to allow users to create the item, the csv parsing is just an addon to our current system

Comment: By web services I meant [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) . This is could be usable when you need to send items from one system to another.

Comment: thought so, but not practical for our app. We need to allow users take data from excel sheets etc and upload them. Seems custom columns will have to be added by the user on our system after the upload.